# How to assign a integer to a pointer in c?

Tags: c, list, pointers, null, function-pointers

The task is to create a function

```
 int* pairSumSearch(int* data, int numEls, int pairSum)
```

that searches within the first numEls of a list if ints 'data', to find two adjacent integers that sum to 'pairSum' and return a pointer to the position of the  first of the two integers. If there are not two ints that sum to pairsum then the function should return a null pointer. I think i have all the code right except for the pointers part.

```
int* pairSumSearch(int* data, int numEls, int pairSum) 
{
    int* point = NULL;
    int checker = data[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numEls-1; i++) {
        if (checker + data[i] == pairSum) {
            *point = i-1;
            break;
        } else {
            checker = data[i];
        }
    }
    return point;
}
```

Test case is

```
int main(void)
{
    int data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 9, 10}; 
    int* p = pairSumSearch(data, 10, 19);
    if (p != NULL) {
        printf("Found at position %zd\n", p - data);
    }
    else {
        puts("Not found");
    }
}
```

but i just get seg faults  where instead it should return

```
Found at position 8
```

Comment: Where does it seg fault? What line? Have you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: NO!!!! `int* point` becomes an INVALID ADDRESS when pairSumSearch() exits.  In this case, you should just return an "int" value.  Alternatively, you can initialize an array in the caller, the write to the array in pairSumSearch().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

```
*point = i-1;
```

Should be

```
point = &data[i-1];
```

Without the starting `*`.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to question you're asking:

> How to assign a integer to a pointer in c

is pretty easy. You don't. A pointer contains an address. You should never (ok, there are special cases, but you're not there yet) assign an integer to a pointer. You're asking the wrong question, because you don't want to do that.

What `*point = i-1` means is change the value of the memory at address `point` to `i-1`.

As Miguel explained, `*point = i-1` is completely wrong and should be `point = &data[i-1]`. It seems like you're trying to return the index, but what you are supposed to return a pointer.

I think you should find a pointer tutorial. There are plenty online.

> Found at position 8

Nope it should print `Found at position 7` since the first index is zero.

Your code is a bit messy though. This is much cleaner.

```
int* pairSumSearch(int* data, int numEls, int pairSum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numEls-1; i++) {
        if (data[i] + data[i+1] == pairSum) {
            return &data[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The mistake in your code is in this line:
 `*point = i-11;`

You are trying to store index(data) and not an address(pointer) at the location where `point` is pointing.

The thing is, your `int *` variable `point` doesn't have any memory allocated to it. Or in other terms, your pointer is not pointing anywhere.

Either you directly point to an index of array `data`. e.g. `point = &(data[i-1])`, then you would be able to return an address of the former element of the pair, and your code will work fine.

You are getting segmentation fault because you are trying to store `i-1` to a location where there is no memory(or not sufficient memory).

Though it would semantically wrong as per your test method, if you want to make that statement to work without generating an error, you should allocate memory to `int *point`. e.g. `int *point = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));`.